# accessing system fonts for document.execCommand?

Tags: javascript, execcommand

So I am using [execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fontname) (with FontName command) on a text edit area (much like [TinyMC editor](http://www.tinymce.com/)), but I am not sure how to access the list of most common system fonts on a machine.

Or rather, should one specify certain most common used fonts and expect that they are found on the client machine?

(I did my homework and I didn't find any other thread on this subject).

thanks,
Gabstero

Comment: Well... I know nothing about execCommand, but it is Ok for you I can give a script which will go through a list of fonts and check if current browser supports it

Comment: Thanks FAngel! That will do it! I am curious of the script! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to site with that script: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Usage is pretty simple:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var detective = new Detector();
    alert(detective.detect('font name'));
};
```

On my project it helped me a lot.